# How to Perform Interlocked.Increment/Decrement Properly in IO Bound?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have simple IO bound 4.0 console application, which send 1 to n requests to a web-service and wait for their completion and then exit. Here is a sample,

```
static int counter = 0;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
foreach (my Loop)
{
    ......................
    WebClientHelper.PostDataAsync(... =>
    {

        ................................
        ................................
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref counter);
    });
    Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);
}
    while(counter != 0)
    {
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

Is this is correct implementation?

Comment: `counter != 0` is not thread safe. You should use interlockedcompare as well

Comment: @MatheusFreitas, can you post the answer?

Comment: I believe you should not perfom this in the main thread. I don't have a complete solution yet

Comment: I would use something like this: Create a thread to post each data, and wait for them finish

Comment: Just like @Sriram answer

Comment: It is not correct.  And it is ugly.  Use the CountDownEvent class instead.

Comment: @HansPassant, can you post an answer?

Comment: Is that really necessary?  It is a very simple class to use, hard to get it wrong.

Comment: @HansPassant, it will helpull for me as well as other. BTW, I will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Hans, here's your code implemented with [`CountdownEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var counter = new CountdownEvent();
    foreach (my Loop)
    {
        ......................
        WebClientHelper.PostDataAsync(... =>
        {

            ................................
            ................................
            counter.Signal();
        });
        counter.AddCount();
    }

    counter.Wait();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Tasks.  Let TPL manage those things.

```
Task<T>[] tasks = ...;
//Started the tasks
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

Another way is to use [TaskCompletionSource as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20354878/2530848).

Comment: @user960567 This is nice. Why to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @user960567 Pass your for-loop method in the Task constructor.

Comment: I am using 4.0 and C# APM.

Comment: You can pretty much convert APM to TPL. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997423%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will help you

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, I was not able to convert webclient.UploadValuesCompleted into TPL. Can u?

Comment: So you're using `UploadValuesAsync`? You can change it to `Task.Run(()=> webclient.UploadValues());`?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, Task.Run. It will spawn a new thread just for wasting purpose.

Comment: No why it need to create thread? It uses `ThreadPool` thread. I agree it is not good when compared to really async methods

Comment: I have converted this to TPL in a more better way, you can update your answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20354089/convert-webclient-to-tpl-in-net-4-0