# Convert WebClient to TPL in .NET 4.0?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have the following webclient code,

```
public static void PostDataAsync(string url, NameValueCollection parameters, object state, Action<object, UploadValuesCompletedEventArgs> callback)
{
    var client = new WebClient();
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    client.UploadValuesCompleted += new UploadValuesCompletedEventHandler(callback);
    client.UploadValuesAsync(new Uri(url), null, parameters, state);
}
```

I want to convert this into Task. I am trying to do this with Task.Factory.FromAsync but failed

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Show us how you tried.

Comment: If you're using VS2012, you can install the Microsoft.Bcl.Async NuGet package and then just use `async/await`.

Comment: @DanielMann: Does that work with .NET 4.0?

Comment: @SLaks, I am using 4.0.

Comment: @DanielMann, Microsoft.Bcl.Async will install C# 5.0 compiler which currently I cannot install it on my srever.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, I have tried something in my answer. Please review.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the answer that I found,

```
public static Task<byte[]> PostDataAsync(string url, NameValueCollection parameters, object state)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<byte[]>(state: state);
    var client = new WebClient();
    client.UploadValuesCompleted += (obj, args) =>
    {
        if (args.Cancelled)
            tcs.SetCanceled();
        else if (args.Error != null)
            tcs.SetException(args.Error);
        else
            tcs.SetResult(args.Result);
    };
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    client.UploadValuesAsync(new Uri(url), null, parameters, state);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: I take the advantage of editing your answer to handle `Cancelled` and `Error`

Comment: @JohnSaunders, `You can accept your own answer in 2 days`